# My node js function runs only the first time, then it then never ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, controller

I have a function "download" that I call every time I click a button. When I click the first time, I see the result and I see in postman that it runs correctly, but when I click again the request never ends. On postman I get "request sending" with no end. Is there an error with my nodejs function?

**My node js function in the controller:**
function download(){

```
    request('http://yoda:9999/fs/mnt/nfs/citstorage/CIT/Reports/DHVD/', function (error, res, html) {
        if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const max=[]
            var maxi=0
            var ind=0
            var name=''
            var st=[]
            $('ul > li > a[href]').each(function(i,e){
              const stt=$(this).text()
              const ma=$(this).text().replace(/[\s-/..]/g, '')
              max.push(ma)
              st.push(stt)
         if (max[i]>maxi) {
            maxi=max[i]
            ind=i
            name=$(this).text()
         }
        
        });
        console.log(name)
        console.log((st[ind]).toString())
        var name2=(st[ind-1]).toString()
        var file = fs.createWriteStream('../json/report.json');
        
            http.get('http://yoda:9999/fs/mnt/nfs/citstorage/CIT/Reports/DHVD/'+name+'VISAGE1/Client/Puppeteer/report.json',(res)=>  {
            
                res.pipe(file);
                let p=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                   file.on('finish', function() {
                     file.close();  
                     console.log('downloaded')
                     resolve('success')
                     reject('failed')
                   });
                })
                p.then((message)=>{
                    shell.exec('npm run test')
                console.log("test completed")
                }).catch((message)=>{
                    http.get('http://yoda:9999/fs/mnt/nfs/citstorage/CIT/Reports/DHVD/'+name2+'VISAGE1/Client/Puppeteer/report.json',function(res)  {
                
                        res.pipe(file);
                        let p=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                           file.on('finish', function() {
                             file.close();  
    
                             console.log('downloaded')
                             resolve('success')
                             reject('failed')
                           });
                        })                            
                        p.then((message)=>{
                         shell.exec('npm run test')
                            
                        console.log("test completed")
                        }).catch((message)=>{
                            console.log("erreur")
                        })
                        
                    })
                })
               })
        }
        
      });
      return Promise.resolve("Success");
    
        },
```

**Axios code vuejs:** show(){Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/users/download')},

Comment: Sounds like the Node server crashes, is there anything in the console?

Comment: A potential bug is a missing index check for `var name2=st[ind]`. `st[]` could be empty.

Comment: @Lissy93 no, i get all the data that i consoled from the code, and it runs correctly, but then when i click the button again nothing appears on my console log and the request on postman never ends

Comment: Which sounds exactly like it's crashing after the first request.